# how to use php to regular the text part and url part?

Tags: php, regex

I do not want to use a simple_html_dom, how to use a php regular to get url part `1.html` `2.html` `3.html` and text part `111` `222` `333`? Thanks.

```
<p>items</p>
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="1.html">111</a></li>
<li><a href="2.html">222</a></li>
<li><a href="3.html">333</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a dom parser? It would be the right tool for the job.

Comment: You mean regular expression ?

Comment: It's even listed on the index page of simple_html_dom website, under quick start. Did you even try to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: @hsz ,yes regular expression.

Comment: @abloodywar, I have get the answer with simple_html_dom, but I still want to learn the regular expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Comment: @cj333: If you want to **learn** the regular expressionS, then visit http://regular-expressions.info/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world - avoid writing `plzsendtehcodez` questions.

Comment: HTML should not be parsed with regex. Ever. If you want to learn regular expressions, learn them on something appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By PHP regular, I'm presuming you mean PERL regular expression.

```
preg_match_all('/<li><a href="([^"]+)">(.+?)<\/a><\/li>/', $html, $matches);
```

Then `$matches[1]` will have a list of the linked documents and `$matches[2]` will have the text.

Comment: that name PERL regular expression. Thanks.

Comment: The matches should rather use `.+?` to avoid eating up too much. Even better would be `[^"]+` and `[^<]+` for specificity.

Comment: By "PERL regular expression", I'm presuming you mean "Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions".